# Best practices deleting many records from several tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2014, spring-jdbc

Having a parent table with millions of records and three child tables with foreign keys pointing to the primary key of the parent table. Like so:

```
  Parent
 parent_id (PK) \       Child1
                |     child1_id (PK)
                |---- parent_id (FK)
                |
                |      Child2
                |     child2_id (PK)
                |---- parent_id (FK)
                |
                |      Child3
                |     child3_id (PK)
                |---- parent_id (FK)
```

What would be the best practice to hard delete hundreds of thousands of records from `Parent`? I want to delete on the following condition: `DELETE FROM PARENT WHERE [STATUS] = 'DONE'`. Is there a way not to lock the table(s) while the delete is happening? So that other records can be inserted in all those tables?
Options I can think of:

1. use `CASCADE DELETE` on the foreign keys.
2. use a soft delete: Start a transaction, `UPDATE parent SET [DELETED] = 1 WHERE [STATUS] = 'DONE'`, delete each child with those parent ids, then hard delete the parents and commit.
3. similar to 2. but using a procedure and saving those ids to be deleted in a table variable so that I don't need to add a new `[DELETED]` column to the `Parent` table.
4. Select Ids to be deleted `SELECT parent_id FROM parent WHERE [STATUS] = 'DONE'` and then do a batch delete passing all these ids. (This performs really badly, so I'm discarding it).

I'm using SQL Server 2014 and spring jdbc.

Comment: I would suggest using a cascade delete on the foreign keys and deleting batches of up to 50,000 records each time. Deleting a lot of records usually speeds up when breaking it down to smaller batches.

Comment: I'm a fan of measuring the progress of operations so I'd consider writing a procedure to remove records in small parts. Either go with ON CASCADE DELETE or do it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer to delete in batches using TOP x

So for each child table :

```
DELETE TOP 10000
FROM child1 
FROM child 1 as c1
INNER join parent
On parent_Id = c1.parent_id
AND parent.[STATUS] = 'DONE'
```

Repeat multiple batches for each child table.

Periodically,  you can remove the parent records with no children.

```
DELETE TOP 10000
FROM parent 
FROM parent as p
Left outer join child1 c1
On p.parent_Id = c1.parent_id
AND c1.child_id IS NULL
 Left outer join child2 c2
On p.parent_Id = c2.parent_id
AND c2.child_id IS NULL
Left outer join child3 c3
On p.parent_Id = c3.parent_id
AND c3.child_id IS NULL
WHERE parent.[STATUS] = 'DONE'
```

How many children each parent has will determine how often you run the parent delete. You can of course vary X I would test small, then increment to say 50000

Comment: I cannot just do `DELETE TOP 10000 ... WHERE parent.[STATUS] = 'DONE'` since new 'DONE' records could be inserted and I don't want to delete those. I could probably save all records' ids to be deleted on a table variable or temp table and then delete in batches as you suggest.

Comment: How about an additional clause to the where statements to restrict by date or to order by the id to ensure that only older records are removed

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way not to lock the table(s) while the delete is happening?

Yes.  As you suggest, operating in batches instead of on millions of records at once will improve concurrent access.

I never use cascading delete because it's insidious: it works well with handfulls of rows, but stops cold with millions.  And I never use TOP anything because it's illogical: it works with an arbitrary number instead of some aspect of the data.

Every time I've written a procedure like this, I've used the same technique.  Starting at the bottom, a loop deletes subsets of the data along the primary key.  When delete returns 0 rows affected, move to the next table, and so on, until you can delete the top row, leaving no dangling references.  The basic deletion looks something like this:

```
while @nrows > 0 begin
    delete from Child3
    where -- limitation criteria -- and
    parent_id = (
        select min(parent_id)
        from Parent
        where Status = 'DONE'
    )
    set @nrows = @@rowcount
done
```

If you can't delete all rows for one `parent_id` at one time, for performance reasons, find some limiting subset, and loop on that.  Perhaps a date, and remove a month or a year at a time.  If you can feasibly delete more than one parent at a time, choose a subset of them at a time, and use `exists` instead of just the minimum.

Fortunately, for this purpose you don't need a user-defined transaction.  The rows are toast anyway, and you can restart anywhere, at any point, whether or not any 'DONE' parent still exists.